# Extra Charge for Recurring Transactions on Coinbase

Tags: coinbase.com, recurring-payments

I had a recurring transaction for $1.00 a month posted to my account. For a while the transaction in Coinbase would read $1.00 for some bitcoin. The bitcoin amount would change but never the dollar amount. Now the dollar and the bitcoin amount is changing, to the point that I enter $1.00 a month and when the actual transaction post, the usd dollar amount says $3.00 and some change, why is the dollar and the bitcoin amount changing? Am I being charged for higher fees or something now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coinbase is no longer paying the Bitcoin transaction fees for their customers; they are now shifting that responsibility onto their customers. This extra charge that you are seeing is likely because of this change.